# How to solve com.google.gson.JsonArray cannot be cast while parsing Json file in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, casting, jsonparser

I am parsing json file in java first time. Where my json file structure is fixed one (I can not change this). I have gone through different answers, but didn't help with my json.
I want list of all **Group Name** in one arrylist and **Unit Name** in another arraylist
Please help to resolve this error, Thanks
I used below code and tried to read from json, but failed to parsed.
JSON FILE:

```
[
    {"No":"1","Component":"Amazon","group_id":"1","Group Name":"shop","Unit Name":"UN","PM":"NULL"},
    {"No":"2","Component":"Amazon","group_id":"1","Group Name":"shop","Unit Name":"UM","PM":"NULL"},
    {"No":"3","Component":"Amazon","group_id":"1","Group Name":"shop","Unit Name":"UP","PM":"NULL"},
    {"No":"4","Component":"Amazon","group_id":"1","Group Name":"shop","Unit Name":"SO","PM":"NULL"},
    {"No":"5","Component":"Amazon","group_id":"1","Group Name":"cart","Unit Name":"SP","PM":"NULL"},
    {"No":"6","Component":"Amazon","group_id":"2","Group Name":"payment","Unit Name":"NZ","PM":"TRUE"}
]
```

Code Trial 1 :

```
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
            Object obj = new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader(JSON_FILE_PATH));
            JsonObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getAsJsonObject();
            String groupName = jsonObject.get("Group Name").toString();
            

ERROR: Exception in Test Case: (IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: [])
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: []
```

Code Trial 2:

```
Object obj = new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader(JSON_FILE_PATH));
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) obj;            
String firstName = jsonObject.get("Group Name").toString();

 
ERROR: Exception in Test Case: (ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonArray cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject)
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonArray cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject
```

I have solved this issue with below code :

```
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader(fileName)).getAsJsonArray();
          
            ArrayList<String> pmGrpListFromWebOm = new ArrayList<>();
            for (JsonElement jsonObjectElement : jsonArray) {
                JsonObject jsonObject = jsonObjectElement.getAsJsonObject();
                String grpname= jsonObject.get("Group Name").toString();
                pmGrpListFromWebOm.add(grpname);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON file contains *array* of objects so you should be able to read the `JsonArray` immediately using `parser.parse` method and explicit casting.

Then you should iterate the array and access its `JsonObject` items using `get` method.

```java
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(JSON_FILE_PATH));

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject item = (JsonObject) jsonArray.get(i);
    String groupName = item.get("Group Name").getAsString();
    System.out.printf("%d group=%s%n", i, groupName); // item index and groupName
}
```

The output will be:

```
0 group=shop
1 group=shop
2 group=shop
3 group=shop
4 group=cart
5 group=payment
```

---

However, Gson `JsonParser` is deprecated and it is recommended to use `Gson` object mapper which allows to read/write objects in more type-safe way.

Each item in the example JSON can be considered as a map of key-value pairs, where both key and value are String.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

// prepare type information
Type itemListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>(){}.getType();

// read the list
List<Map<String, String>> list = gson.fromJson(json, itemListType);

// process items in the list
for (Map<String, String> item : list) {
    String no = item.get("No");
    String groupName = item.get("Group Name");
    System.out.printf("no=%s group=%s%n", no, groupName);
}
```

output:

```
no=1 group=shop
no=2 group=shop
no=3 group=shop
no=4 group=shop
no=5 group=cart
no=6 group=payment
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I have tried below code and worked for me.                                                                         JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader(fileName)).getAsJsonArray();
          
            ArrayList<String> pmGrpListFromWebOm = new ArrayList<>();
            for (JsonElement jsonObjectElement : jsonArray) {
                JsonObject jsonObject = jsonObjectElement.getAsJsonObject();
                String firstName = jsonObject.get("Group Name").toString();
                pmGrpListFromWebOm.add(firstName);
            }